# Tips for gracefully loading a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a web page that has a lot of content that is hidden/shown/styled when the page is in various states using jQuery/javascript.  I am running into an issue where on the initial load of the page, all of my content is displayed in a hideous way for a fraction of a second before everything is styled/hidden/displayed how it should on page load.

Can anyone recommend any techniques to have the initial load of the page done in a more graceful way?

Comment: you can allways hide everything at the beginning, and only show what you need to show at the end of your init function.

Comment: Have a `div id="loading"` with a loading graphic of some kind that's `display: block` on page load, hide `div id="content"`, then using Javascript, load things like images and when complete, hide `#loading` and show `#content`. The "trick" is to use CSS to hide and show the appropriate ones, instead of using JS to hide it on load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as a `FOUC` - a flash of unstyled content.

A fairly standard way is to hide the content by default in your css and then once all the manipulation using javascript has been done show the elements again.

However, rather than aiming for `graceful degradation` you may consider trying for `progressive enhancement` to enable javascript to add functionality to your site rather than relying on it for the functionality and appearance.
See [here for a good blog post](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/graceful-degradation-progressive-enhancement/) on the relative merits of the two approaches.

Comment: +1 for mentioning FOUC, but you should probably include a summary of what works for Stack Overflow posterity (in case the blog site is down or deleted).

Comment: by hiding them with CSS and later showing them with JS isn't dangerous?. (in the case the user have JS off?)

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS to set the initial display state to hidden (`display:none` or `visibility:hidden`, as appropriate) and jQuery/JavaScript to show them later (either by direct styling or changing classes such that they appear.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the CSS `display:none` and `visibility:hidden` by default to your hidden elements.

Answer (score 0):

what about adding overlay and hide it when page load complete? :)
try to add a div with id overlay or it's up to you, and style it like this :

```
#overlay{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0; left:0;
  z-index:99
}
```

this will hide all of your content. and after webpage load complete, hide it with jquery :

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#overlay').animate({opacity:'0'}).css('zindex','-10');
})
```