# Is there any event jQuery or JavaScript where I can hide elements before they appears in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Now I have an `onready` event handler:

```
$(function() {
   $('element').hide();
});
```

but element is hiding only after it appears in browser, and it disappear like a flash.

Can I bind any `hide()` function before content appears in my browser?

Comment: I think better to use css style : display=none;. when we need to display that elements we can use display=block;

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494008/tips-for-gracefully-loading-a-web-page) that covers the same topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can i bind any hide() function before content appears in my browser ?

No. The DOM must be loaded first before being able to manipulate it with javascript. The best way is to simply hide the element using CSS from the server side so that it never shows when the page loads. So define a hidden class in your CSS file:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

and then apply it to your element:

```
<div class="hidden">some hidden content</div>
```

Comment: Be careful with this: users who have Javascript disabled will *never* see the content.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, for users who have javascript disabled you could still have graceful degradation: provide a link that will reload the page and when it is rendered for the second time you will remove the hidden class on the server side. So the content will show. It's just that they need to reload the page to see the changes because they have javascript disabled and the DOM cannot be manipulated without reloading.

Comment: Better yet, use something like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to add a `js` class to the `<html>` element when it runs and then only apply the hidden style when `<html>` has the `js` class.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you couldn't apply a class like this to your element

**HTML**

```
<div class="s-hidden">Hello foo!</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.s-hidden { display: none; visibility: hidden; }
```

*Note that `visibility:hidden` also hides the element from screen-readers, which will still read out the content of you leave this off*

Then show it when you need it?

Answer (score 0):

The DOM must be load before you can access and modify it properly using JavaScript. You should use CSS to hide the elements and then later when the DOM has finished loading you´ll be able to show then as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to hide element:

display:none;