# Does jQuery absolutely need hide() before the method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am brand new to JavaScript and jQuery, so please be easy on me.

My jQuery methods aren't working unless there is a hide() method beforehand, which causes the browser to flash the page for a millisecond before jQuery kicks in. Is there any way to avoid this? Example below.

```
        <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#thingId").hide(0).fadeIn(2000);

        });

        </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there any event jquery or javascript where can i hide elements before they appears in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516911/is-there-any-event-jquery-or-javascript-where-can-i-hide-elements-before-they-ap)

Comment: in your css set `display: none` for `#thingId`.

Comment: Try setting the opacity of `#thingId` to `0` since you're fading in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fade something in, it needs to be invisible to start with:)
Just hide it in css with display:none first.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
          #thingId{
             display:none;
           }
    </style>
    </head>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {

          $("#thingId").fadeIn(2000);

      });

    </script>
```